# In React: How can I either stop React from adding a wrapping div, or add a classname to the wrapping div?

Tags: reactjs

I've created a component that outputs a navigation menu.

I'm calling this component from within another component that outputs a website header.

```
export default function HeaderNav() {

    return(


        
        <nav className={styles.headerNav}>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/tests/test001">Test 1</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/tests/test002">Test 2</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/tests/test003">Test 3</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        
    )
}
```

I've found that React is wrapping my navigation component in a parent div:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJYkF.jpg

The addition of this wrapping div creates problems for styling. Especially when it comes to layout for the header.

Ideally I'd like to additional wrapper to not exist. But if there's no way to prevent it from existing, then giving it a classname might help to reduce the issues for styling it.

How can I do either of these things?

Comment: please share your code and output so we might be able to help you.

Comment: @bob.dobbs Can you also show that how are you using this component in another component.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your navigation component between `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>` or with shorthand `<></>`. To further read about [React.Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)